# Setting Struts2 Multiselect dropdown value using jquery

Tags: jquery, struts

I have an requirement in my project where i am getting array of comma separated values from ajax,
what i need to do is to show dropdown entries selected by setting options value from array to multiselect.
my jquery code is as follows,

```
$.ajax({   
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'getInputAction',
                data: {'doc_id': doc_id,'dcr_id':dcrId},
                success: function(response) {
                    var input = $.trim(response);
                    var prim = input.split("#")[0];
                    var sec = input.split("#")[1];
                    var PrimVals = prim.split("@");
                    var secVals = sec.split("@");
```

> $("#SEC1@1").val(secVals);

```
                    $.each(PrimVals, function(i,e){
                        $("#PRIM1@1").find("option[value="+e+"]").prop("selected","selected");
                    }); 
                }
});
```

and Jsp code

```
<td>
    <s:select theme="simple"  tabindex="8" id="PRI1@1" cssClass="mediumSelect" cssStyle="width:50%;" list="prodList" name="DETAILED1" multiple="true" required="true" />
</td>
```

Above highlighted code is not working .
Please can anybody help me ,
Thanks

Comment: can you post your secVals? Is that comma separated values?

Comment: If you are using struts2 why dont you try `Struts2 jquery Drop down` ?

Comment: Hi @looser,@vinoth i m not using jquery drop down, just setting option value in jquery geeting in jquery response i.e comma seperated array,

Comment: SecVals 1,2,3,0,0 @VinothKrishnan

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need to refresh your multiselect dropdown after setting values in it. Like this,

Here is your html part,

```
<select name="test" id="testId" multiple>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Value 3</option>
    <option value="4" selected>Value 4</option>
</select>
```

And here is your updated javascript part,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var values= [1,2,3];
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = values.length; i <l; i++){
        newArray.push(values[i]);
    }
    $("#testId").val(newArray);
    jQuery("#testId").multiselect("refresh");
});
```

You can find your working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/93C9R/2/)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Amol Please make sure that your array does not contain any duplicate values like `1,2,3,0,0` also `null` values.

Comment: thanks, i am already having string as 1@2@3@0@0 after splitting it will give an array of [1,2,3,0,0], now after getting array i cant split it as values.split(",") as its final array got after splitting;

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer above. Please check again.